# Using a plugin to call Google Maps API from within Leaflet in R

Tags: r, google-maps-api-3, leaflet, htmlwidgets

I am new here and wanted help to figure out how to call a Google Maps base layer using the Google Maps API in a Leaflet map in R. Here's what I have learnt till now:

1. Pavel Shramov's Leaflet plugins allow Google's base maps to be called from inside Leaflet JS, in a manner that is, from what I understand, compliant with Google's ToS. An example of this is [available here](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins/blob/master/examples/google.html), which works quite well.
2. There are general instructions on [using arbitrary Leaflet JS plugins in Leaflet for R](https://bl.ocks.org/jcheng5/c084a59717f18e947a17955007dc5f92) via htmltools and htmlwidgets.

Based on the above, I understand that my code in R will need to look somewhat as follows, but I can't get a Google basemap to load:

```
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)

# 1: Tell htmlwidgets where to look for the script and stylesheets
gLeafletPlugin <- htmlDependency("gLeaflet","1.9.0",
                           src = c(href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-plugins/1.9.0/layer/tile/"),
                           script = "Google.js")

# FIRST PLACE WHERE I AM STUCK: I am pretty sure, I also need to pass on 
# the Google Maps API script reference before or along with the above command,
# but trying to include two htmlDependency objects together in a list, did not
# work. Maybe I wasn't doing it right.


# 2: Make a map and add the htmlDependency object to it
registerPlugin <- function(map, plugin) {
    map$dependencies <- c(map$dependencies, list(plugin))
    map
    }

leaflet() %>% 
  setView(76.65, 12.32, zoom = 9) %>%
    registerPlugin(gLeafletPlugin) %>%
      # 3: Pass on custom JS logic: SECOND PLACE WHERE I AM STUCK
      onRender("function(el, x) {
         L.Google('TERRAIN').addTo(this);
        }")
```

Would be grateful if someone could show me: (a) the correct way of registering the htmlDependency, when more than one script is involved; and (b) the correct syntax to call the extra JS logic needed to display a Google Terrain basemap.

Thanks!

Comment: If it's any help, I'm developing a Google Maps widget (http://gallery.htmlwidgets.org/ - search for 'google') as part of my [`googleway`](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) package. It's not complete, but it is functional.

Comment: Thanks, will check it out.

Comment: As I'm still developing it, feel free to let me know of any changes or additions you think would be good; always looking for feedback.